# bibdata command

Tags: bibtex, external-files

My `.aux` file says `\bibdata{all}`. How can I find out which of several files named `all.bib` is being interrogated? Presumably this depends on some path defined in my copy of TeX. How do I find out which path is being used by BibTeX?

Is there a way of persuading BibTeX to give the full path name of the database it is using, just as the TeX `.log` file gives the full path names of the files it is using?

How does one make an enhancement request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run

```
bibtex8 -d io <file>
```

then you'll get some "debug" information of the io (input/output) process. Pay attention for the "8" it is the 8bit version of the old `bibtex`. For more debug options see `bibtex8 -h` or run `texdoc bibtex8`. However, `bibtex` searches its files via `kpsewhich`

Comment: I tried "man bibtex8" and there was no mention of the argument "io". Is there a fuller version of the manual somewhere? Herbert's command did function as advertised. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no manual page for `bibtex8`. Run `texdoc bibtex8`